# back button navigation bar not change image swift

Tags: ios, swift, navigation

I have a navigation controller in which I have created my navigation bar, now when I go to a new screen I would like to change my left icon of the navigation. but it doesn't work

```
    var wwwe = TPCustomNavigationViewController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.wwwe.backButton?.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "arrow_gray_sx"), for: .normal)
    self.wwwe.backButton?.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "arrow_gray_sx"), for: .selected)

    guard let url = URL(string: "https://toduba-website-test.clikapp.vercel.app/helpdesk") else {
        return
    }
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    webview?.load(request)
}
```

Comment: `self.wwwe.backButton` Is it nil? `TPCustomNavigationViewController` you are creating a whole new instance, is that the one shown on screen?

Comment: @Larme in TPCustomNavigationViewController there is the backButton which I set the correct image for all the views in which it is used. only in this view where I wrote the code I would like a different icon, but if I access the property and try to change it imagine nothing changes

Comment: `(self.navigationController as? TPCustomNavigationViewController).backButton?.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "arrow_gray_sx"), for: .normal)` instead. What you don't understand, is that when you do `let wwe = TPCustomNavigationViewController()` it's in fact `let wwe = TPCustomNavigationViewController.init()` meaning it's a NEW object, not an existing one, not the one seeing in screen.

Comment: if you push to another controller and need that it change from there, put your code in viewWillAppear() method this will call when you pop from another VC.

Comment: @Larme oh ok understood, I created a new one without then showing it in practice .. ok it works I change the icon. But I have a problem now, that when I re-access the controllers it always displays this icosa and not the i anymore

Comment: @guru I inserted it where you told me but it does not change the behavior, when I return to the old controllers I have the image of this controller and no longer the initial one

Comment: I don't understand why you create  new object, check it, if its nil.
var wwwe = TPCustomNavigationViewController()

Answer (score 0):

Hi to access your navigation bar item you can proceed like that

```
let img = UIImage(named: "navbar-image")
navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(img, for: .default)
```

Answer (score 0):

ok resolved whit this

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    (self.navigationController as? TPCustomNavigationViewController)?.backButton?.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "arrow_gray_sx"), for: .normal)
    (self.navigationController as? TPCustomNavigationViewController)?.backButton?.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "arrow_gray_sx"), for: .selected)
}
```